# Proftpd login fails on CentOS

Tags: linux, authentication, ftp, proftpd

I'm trying to connect ftp server on Cent OS. Ftp server is proftpd.

I added new user, mike,  for ftp.

When I'm trying to connect ftp server via CuteFTP, it gives me error "login incorrect", even though username and password are correct.

I tried to find solution on google, and I got some article about this. And it says, I have to add the ftp user to xftp group by editing `/etc/group`.

But there was not details how to edit this.

I'm a newbie to linux.

Any advise will be thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the man page,

usermod -a -G xftp mike

should do the trick. You have to be root or have sudo set up.